# Searching Google Groups using Directory API

Tags: get, google-directory-api, google-groups-api

I am trying to retrieve Google groups using the directory API with partial matches and wildcards.

The API allows me to retrieve a group if I know an alias using
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey

I can retrieve all groups using
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?customer=my_customer

There doesn't seem to be a way to search for a subset of the groups, for example returning all groups that start with foo.

Some of our customers have huge numbers of groups so retrieving them all is impractical.